# Why is this code not clicking EVERY element in list?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, staleelementreferenceexception

I am trying to go into every city one by one here but after the program comes back from the first page, it does not go into the next page and displays `StaleElementReferenceException` error.

This is my code:

```
url = "https://www.agoda.com/region/punjab-province-pk.html"

s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get(url)

a = ActionChains(driver)

cities = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='dt[data-selenium="neighbor-name"]')

for city in cities:
    print(city.text)
    a.double_click(city).perform()
    print(driver.current_url)
    driver.back()
```

Even though when I just print elements in list it displays all of them but does not print or click when I write these lines of code used to navigate forward and back.

What am I doing wrong here?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you going to another page by clicking the `city` all the web elements initially collected in `cities` list on the main page are becoming stale. In Selenium Web Element is actually a reference to a physical web element. When you coming back to the main page it is re-rendered so the previously collected references to web elements no more pointing to those elements.
To make your code working you need to collect the `cities` list again when getting back to the main page.
The following should work:

```py
cities = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='dt[data-selenium="neighbor-name"]')

for idx, city in enumerate(cities):
    city = cities[idx]
    print(city.text)
    a.double_click(city).perform()
    print(driver.current_url)
    driver.back()
    cities = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'dt[data-selenium="neighbor-name"]')))
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much for this. You also explained the the problem very clearly.

Comment: It's my pleasure :)